# Have a way to simulate diamond problem with Java

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Have a way to simulate [the diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) with Java ? With interfaces ?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can never have a diamond problem. It's designed **not to have multiple inheritance**.

Diamond problem comes when you have multiple data members  and function member with solid definition in the super base class. However, in Java you can only have `interface` getting implemented; which never can contain anything other than pure `virtual`  methods and `static const` members (in C++ context).

Answer (score 0):

Java avoids the diamond problem by enforcing single-inheritance for classes and allowing multiple inheritance for interfaces.

It's not really a problem when interfaces form a diamond.

You can get a Javadoc diamond problem, but I guess that's not what you're looking for.